# Java: KMP matcher algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, knuth-morris-pratt

[image]

I am trying to implement the above algorithm in Java. However I am getting an out of bounds exception and I don't know how to fix this.

I am just translating the psuedocode pretty much line by line.

Here is the code:

```
public static int[] computePrefixFunction(String input) 
    {
        int[] pi = new int[input.length()];
        int k = 0;
        for (int q = 1; q < input.length(); q++) {
            char target = input.charAt(q);
        while (k > 0 && input.charAt(k) != target) k = pi[k - 1];
        if (input.charAt(k) == target) k++;
        pi[q] = k;
    }
    return pi;
}

public static Queue<Integer> KMPMatcher(String T, String P) 
{
    int n = T.length();
    int m = P.length();
    int[] pi = computePrefixFunction(P);
    int q = 0;
    Queue<Integer> Q = new LinkedList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        while(q > 0 && P.charAt(q+1) != T.charAt(i)) 
            q = pi[q];
        if(P.charAt(q+1) == T.charAt(i)) 
            q = q + 1;
        if(q == m-1) // you match it when q reaches size of pattern -1. :)
        {
            Q.add(i-m+1); // Change it as well.
            q = pi[q];
        }     
    }
    return Q;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(KMPMatcher("bdacabdacb","bda"));
}
```

Edit: I have updated the code with piyush implementation below which corrected a few of my problems. However there is another problem.

I tested KMPMatcher using these:

1)    `System.out.println(KMPMatcher("bacabab","bab")); // returned`[2,4]

2)    `System.out.println(KMPMatcher("bdacabdacb","bab")); // returned`[3]

Number 1 should only return 4 and number 2 should only return an empty list. Why is this happening? I am trying to draw at the trace with these inputs and compare it with the psuedocode. I think it something to do with the indexing in the `if(q==m-1)`(because its not comparing the right thing compared to the psuedocode version?) and I'm not sure how to fix it. Any help please?

Comment: the prefix function is correct, I have tested it and it returns what's expected. Only the KMPMatcher method has the error

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could tell us on which line the Exception occurs.

Comment: @StephaneM sorry I have updated it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in `if` statement. It should not be  `if (q == m-1)`.

```
public static int[] computePrefixFunction(String input) 
    {
        int[] pi = new int[input.length()];
        int k = 0;
        for (int q = 1; q < input.length(); q++) {
            char target = input.charAt(q);
        while (k > 0 && input.charAt(k) != target) k = pi[k - 1];
        if (input.charAt(k) == target) k++;
        pi[q] = k;
    }
    return pi;
}

   public static Queue<Integer> KMPMatcher(String T, String P) 
{
    int n = T.length();
    int m = P.length();
    int[] pi = computePrefixFunction(P);
    int q = 0;
    Queue<Integer> Q = new LinkedList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        while(q > 0 && P.charAt(q) != T.charAt(i)) 
            q = pi[q-1];
        if(P.charAt(q) == T.charAt(i)) 
            q++;
        {
            Q.add(i-q+1); // Change it.
            q = pi[q-1];
        }     
    }
    return Q;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(KMPMatcher("bdacabdacb","bda"));
}
```

Comment: isn't there something wrong with this solution? It returns [-1,4] but it should be [1,5]

Comment: I found some problems with your KMP matcher: With string "bacababa" and pattern "bab it returns [2,4] but the 2 should not in the result. And with string  "bdacabdacb" and pattern "bab" it returns [3] which is not correct. Why is that?

Comment: Hey, Thank you for pointing that out. Made some few changes in the code. The problem was in " Q.add(i-m+1) " . You should check the algorithm again.